# Searching from a RecyclerView

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I currently have a functioning RecyclerView within my Android Studio application. Users are required to input A name and 4 different values. This RecyclerView is functioning through SQL and works no problem when inputting data. The data updates when the RecyclerView is displayed and all data is positioned perfectly and everything works well.

I have implemented the Search function at the top of the RecyclerView meaning users can search for a specific name. However it seems when using the search function that they data displayed beside the name updates to get the current position of the data in the ArrayList. This isn't the case when normally viewing the List, would this be something I done wrong when implementing the Search function? See below for code regarding the search:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {
UserLoginAdapter userLoginAdapter;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> FoodID, FoodName, Calories;
private ArrayList<String> FoodNameDuplicate;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList FoodID, ArrayList FoodName, ArrayList Calories, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.FoodID = FoodID;
    this.FoodName = FoodName;
    this.Calories = Calories;
    FoodNameDuplicate = new ArrayList<>(FoodName);
    mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foodrows, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.FoodID.setText(String.valueOf(FoodID.get(position)));
    holder.FoodName.setText(String.valueOf(FoodName.get(position)));
    holder.Calories.setText(Calories.get(position));  //(String.valueOf(Calories.get(position)));

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, holder.getAdapterPosition());
            //Toast.makeText(context, Calories.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("calories", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("caloriesInput", Calories.get(position));
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomePage.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);

            //AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();
            //FoodDiaryFragment foodDiaryFragment = new FoodDiaryFragment();
            //appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.inputRecyclerView, foodDiaryFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return FoodName.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView FoodID, FoodName, Calories;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        FoodID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_FoodID);
        FoodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_FoodNameTextView);
        Calories = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_FoodCaloriesTextView);
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return foodFilter;
}

private Filter foodFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        ArrayList<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
            filteredList.addAll(FoodNameDuplicate);
        } else {
            java.lang.String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for(String item : FoodNameDuplicate){
                if(item.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        FoodName.clear();
        FoodName.addAll((ArrayList)results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
  };
 }
```

RecyclerView java file:

```
public class InputFoodToDiary extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
UserDatabase userDatabase;
ArrayList<String> FoodID, FoodName, Calories;

CustomAdapter customAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inputfoodtodiary);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_InputFood);

    userDatabase = new UserDatabase(InputFoodToDiary.this, "CALTOR", null, 1);

    FoodID = new ArrayList<>();
    FoodName = new ArrayList<>();
    Calories = new ArrayList<>();

    storeDataInArrays();

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(InputFoodToDiary.this, FoodID, FoodName, Calories, new CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Calories.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(InputFoodToDiary.this));
}

void storeDataInArrays(){
    Cursor cursor = userDatabase.readAllData();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            FoodID.add(cursor.getString(0));
            FoodName.add(cursor.getString(1));
            Calories.add(cursor.getString(2));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.food_search, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            customAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already taken item as String you dont need to add toString() method to it.

Try this:

```
 for(String item : FoodNameDuplicate){
   
     if(item.toLowerCase().contains(filterpattern)){
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: getText1 doesn't appear as a method for me; where is this referenced and how do I implement it?

Comment: actually i forgot to add () after getText1.Check the answer now.

Comment: getText1() still doesn't appear for me, where is this referenced?

Comment: Check my updated answer. InSha Allah this time it will work.

Comment: Kevin do accept my answer if that worked for you

Comment: No unfortunately this didn't work, I am still having the same problem

Comment: Please be more clear in your explanation.

Comment: However it seems when using the search function that they data displayed beside the name updates to get the current position of the data in the ArrayList.Didnt got what do you mean by this sentence.

Comment: Ok, when searching using the Search Filter within my RecyclerView, the Food Name filters accurately so if I type "Banana"; Banana will appear. However the calories which is placed beside the Banana is not correct; this value doesn't update along with the search results, it stays the same and is the 1st value within the column.

Comment: Do you mean to say only the title changes to banana but the data remains the same as of 1st position.Let say you have apple with its calorie at first position and babana at some ither position but when you search banana the title is banana with data of apple.

Comment: Also upload the search view initialisation code i.e where and how you are passing query

Comment: Yes that is correct regarding the apple situation; the title changes surrounding the search filter however the calories stay the same. I have added all changes to the code above regarding the search filter.

Comment: Try using if(item.getHeader().toLowerCase().contains(filterpattern)).

Comment: No this doesn't seem to work either; .getHeader() doesn't appear as a method.

Comment: you need to see what your are using to get foodname then use that inplace of getheader().

Comment: I watched few of a tutorial on youtube on this and saw them doing this only.If you want i can send you link for reference.